# Artisan returns blank

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

Whenever I run any `php artisan` command like `php artisan list`, I get nothing back. No commands work at all.

I have been searching a little around, and have tried the following:

- changing permissions for `/root/.composer` to 777
- remove `bootstrap/compiled.php` file

There is nothing in `app/storage/logs/log-cli-.txt`.
I can view the site in the browser.

I'm running on CentOS 6.3 64bit with PHP v. 5.5.11 - Laravel 4.1

Comment: does php cli work at all ? did you try running some sort of `php example.php` to check the php command prompt or is it just artisan that is dead ? :)

Comment: @Gadoma PHP Cli works. Just tried to run `php test.php` with a test file made with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`, and it works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This problem is pretty common and is usually related to some errors that are not seen in the CLI like custom classes that failed to load, are you sure you have error reporting on?

Edit the file `artisan` and add the following lines just after the PHP opening tag `<?php`:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

Try running `artisan` again and see if there is any output.

If that doesn't work try reverting `app/start/global.php` to it's default state.

Comment: Done both, without any luck. Thanks for the try anyways.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith in 2018 PHP didn't change that much, the reason is somewhere in artisan/Laravel these settings are overwritten, so you may just find this place and comment it out temporarily.

Comment: The problem in the client's codebase was that there was an `exit` inside a Controller's `__construct()`. That killed `artisan` without anything returning for `route:list`.

Answer (score 6):

Running `composer install` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was like @TheodoreR.Smith mentioned, there was an `exit` in a controller's `__construct()`. I removed it and `route:list` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Came here after a cronjob wouldn't execute because of artisan containing an error in the CLI, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23647690/4668696) answer. So dropping my answer in case it could help someone.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56658142/laravelsyntax-error-in-vendor-laravel-framework-src-illuminate-support-arr-php) is switching to PHP 7.1+ (7.2 in my case) due to Laravel requirements.

Switching to 7.2 for me, wasn't enough. Both Apache and CLI were switched to 7.2 but the cronjob uses the default PHP version of the server (cPanel managed). Specifically executing the 7.2 version (in stead of global PHP) solved it for me, the cronjob command is:

```
 * * * * * /usr/local/bin/ea-php72 /path/to/laravel/artisan schedule:run >/dev/null 2>&1
```

(remove `> /dev/null 2>&1` if you want to see the output and bugfix the commands)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have any exit() or die() in your route file.

That was the issue in my case as I was in the middle of testing some code in the route file when I realized that I couldn't run any artisan command.