# Laravel:syntax error in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 384

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I tried to make a new laravel project work on my debian vps but nothing go right. I init the project with the basic `composer create-project laravel/laravel`, change the permissions to `755` so everything that is explained [here](https://devmarketer.io/learn/deploy-laravel-5-app-lemp-stack-ubuntu-nginx).

But I always have an `error 500` when I tried to access to my `<pathToMyProject>/public` folder and when I read my php's logs is see this message :

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=' in /vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php  on line 384

What can be the problem ? I precise that my php version is `>7.1`

Comment: Woaw i'm so sorry for this mistake but my php version is `>7.1`. I updated my post

Comment: Are you sure your server is running php >7.1, not that you just have php >7.1 on your pc?

Comment: ok, Laravel 5.8 requires PHP >= 7.1.3 and some more [server requirements](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/installation#server-requirements). you can check that you have all the required extensions installed and activated by putting a [phpinfo.php](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) file in your public folder and opening in your browser http://your-domain/phpinfo.php. you can also run `php -v`  via ssh, to make sure that the version is correct

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced the same problems. I resolved it by running the following commands.

> php -v

It displays the current running php version `=> 7.0`

> a2dismod php7.0

It will be disabled php7.0 version.

> a2enmod php7.2

It will be enabled php7.2 version.

> service apache2 restart

Answer (score 7):

It is possible that the CLI version of PHP is 7.2 but apache is using an older version of PHP. Would be worth adding a `phpinfo.php` in the root of your public folder containing

```
<?php 

phpinfo();
```

the navigate to your http://www.yoursite.com/phpinfo.php and double check the version.

Ensure you remove the `phpinfo.php` file once you have tested.

Answer (score 0):

Just Ensure you upgrade your php version on the server like from 7.0 to something like 7.3. if you are using the CPanel navigate to **Web Tools** then **PHP Configuration** and change the php version

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error using laravel in cpanel.

1. Go to composer.json
2. Check PHP version
3. Go to the Cpanel dashboard
4. Software > Select PHP version
5. change PHP version to $php_version
6. save and retry

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I have only installed `php 7.0`.

If it is your problem too. Do bellow step for installing `7.2`:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install php7.2
```