# Laravel 6: Cannot run any artisan command on the server

Tags: ssh, laravel-artisan, laravel-6

**[UPDATE]**

edited artisan file like this

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
```

and I got this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home/u635130117/domains/example.com/public_html/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 500
```

Here's the code

```
if (isset($arguments[1]) && is_string($arguments[1])) {
        return $factory->of($arguments[0], $arguments[1])->times($arguments[2] ?? null); //line 500
    } elseif (isset($arguments[1])) {
        return $factory->of($arguments[0])->times($arguments[1]);
    }
```

---

I have connected to the shared hosting using SSH but can't run any artisan command like clearing cache or listing artisan commands I get nothing at all no output. I tested creating a new command and it's not created too.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible that the commands are executing but you didn't get any output because of security settings of your shared hosting provider? Try to generate a new key with `php artisan key:generate` and the check if something has changed in your env file.

Comment: I tried creating a new command TestEmail and it's not generated.

Comment: Other bash command are working?

Comment: yes like `mkdir` it works

Comment: Hmm that's weird. Try to make a php script which does something and check if the execution of a normal php script is working.

Comment: execution of php script is fine I can send email from the controller

Comment: Here's a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641726/artisan-returns-blank. Try some stuff from there. This could eventually help you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Artisan returns blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641726/artisan-returns-blank)

Comment: Updated the question please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parse error occurs if the php version is to low. So we discovered there are more than one versions of php installed on the server after the execution of `php -v` returned php version `5.6.40`.

Finally in the phpinfo were the path of the php 7 version which is also being used by the webserver. This was `/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php`.

Commands can now executed by using `/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php` like `/opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php artisan key:generate`.

You can also create an alias like `php7` or just `php` for this. It's described [here](https://www.tecmint.com/create-alias-in-linux/).

Comment: I have this in htaccess to enable v 7.2 while other domains and the main domain use v 5.6 `AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php` should I add these 2 lines too you suggested in htaccess?

Comment: info() says PHP Version 7.2.25

Comment: What's the response if your executing `php -v`?

Comment: PHP 5.6.40 (cli)  why is that?

Comment: That's a very good question but this produces your problem. Try executing `which php` to check where php is installed and then you can check in those folders for an another version. But first check `php7 -v` or something. I've had this once that my provider created an alias for php 7 and so the command `php` was for version 5.6 and `php7` was for version 7.2

Comment: Check if an other php version is installed in your `/usr/bin` directory.

Comment: just php and php-cgi no php7

Comment: Please have a look at this screenshot to see if this helps  https://ibb.co/wL45Y3Z

Comment: Thank you for the screenshot. It's a mess your provider is creating... Try to execute an artisan command with `/opt/alt/php72` instead of `php` like this: `/opt/alt/php72 artisan key:generate`

Comment: nothing changed and I get this : /opt/alt/php72: Is a directory

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the content of this folder?

Comment: So try to execute `/opt/alt/php72/php -v`.

Comment: /opt/alt/php72/usr/bin/php artisan config:cache and other commands worked with the correct output thanks a lot please add the solution so I accept it I think it will be useful for others. Thanks again

Comment: I've edited the answer. No problem I like solving such problems ;)