# Laravel 6.2 artisan commands returns blank/empty output

Tags: laravel

Well, This is confusing me, because all artisan commands return blank/empty output whenever I run an artisan command like: `php artisan serve`

I also tried to edit the artisan file in the root folder to echo a string and it works, the terminal gave me an output.

Why do artisan commands return like this empty output?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23641726/artisan-returns-blank) answer your question?

Comment: @SumitWadhwa Nope, Actually I tried that method to enable error reporting, but I am not getting any errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been caused by `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

There was a code to validate the license code inside this service provider. I removed it. Now it's fine.